# Form submitting in chrome but not on any other browser

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, forms, http-post

I'm pushing my code using Visual Studio Publish option.

The problem I'm facing is when I publish my code to Azure Web App and after I switch it with my main site.

Till then everything works fine, but after swapping register login nothing works.
It may look weird but when we use the same register and login with Chrome it works fine, but when I try to replicate the same in other browsers it wont work. It's not hitting the method for post and server is returning 500 in response.

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="RegisterPost" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="signup-form" data-bind="submit: submitForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 register-input">
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 register-input">
            <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 register-input">
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 register-input">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 register-input"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 register-input">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 register-input">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 register-help">
            <span class="help-text">at least 8 characters, must include a number</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 center-block">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-action">Signup</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The script I'm using for submitting the form:

```
self.submitForm = function () {                
    if ($("#signup-form").valid()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

The controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("/register")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterPost(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, RolesEnum.Candidate.ToString());
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(model.Email);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(AccountController.VerifyPhone));
        }

        if (result.Errors != null && result.Errors.Any(e => e.Code == "DuplicateUserName"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register", new { err = "exists" });
        }
    }
    return View("Register", model);
}
```

Comment: Does it work locally? is it a .net mvc project? You can use fiddler to see what is happening when you click the submit button.

Comment: @IvanYang its working locally only after publishing on production its throwing this error

Comment: Is it a .net mvc project?

Comment: its .net core project and yah it follows mvc